# React not rendering with correct state value after using this.setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a component that automatically checks an input field for a valid email address, then adds it to an array using `setState`.

I have that part working correctly, but I also want it to remove the last item when you backspace on the empty field.

The problem I am having is that when I splice the last item in the array, and update it using `setState`, it doesnt render the new array value?

If I log the value in the function called by `onKeyDown`, it logs the correct updated array value of `this.state.emails`. The render function however logs the old value and the list doesnt update.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/adamcoulombe/pen/zJxoER

```
class MultiEmailInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            emails:[]
        };
    }
    fieldChange(e){
        if (e.target.value !== ''){
            if (this.validateEmail(e.target.value)===true){
                this.setState({emails: this.state.emails.concat(e.target.value)});

            }
        }
    }
    fieldKeyDown(e){
       // console.log(e.target.value);
        if(e.target.value===''){
            var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
            if (key == 8 || key == 46) {

                this.setState({ emails: this.state.emails.splice(-1) });
                //logs correct updated value
                console.log(this.state.emails);

            }
        }
    }
    validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
    }
  render() {
       //this value doesnt get updated?
      console.log(this.state.emails);
    return (
      <div className={"email-multi-input"+this.props.className}>
            <ul className="added-emails" ref="email-multi-input-added-emails">

                {

                    this.state.emails.map((email, i) => {
                    return (<li key={i}>{email}</li>)
                })}
            </ul>

            <input ref="email-multi-input-field" onChange={this.fieldChange.bind(this)} onKeyDown={this.fieldKeyDown.bind(this)} />
     </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(
    <MultiEmailInput />, 
    document.body
);
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wgbomp

Comment: Try `this.setState({ emails: this.state.emails.slice(0, this.state.emails.length-1)})`

Comment: Thanks! that worked!! I guess I was using the wrong function?

Comment: how come you were getting the correct updated state then ?

Comment: Thats a great question. I am still a little puzzled why the value was coming up differently inside the render function

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with this line in `fieldKeyDown`:

```
this.setState({ emails: this.state.emails.splice(-1) });
```

the `splice`  method mutates the array `this.state.emails` and removes the last element, however it *returns* that last element. So that line above sets `this.state.emails` equal to the last element of `this.state.emails`.

The reason you see the correct value when you call `console.log(this.state.emails)` in `fieldKeyDown` is because the effect of `this.setState` has not taken place yet since React does not update state immediately (See [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)). So you are looking at the old `this.state.emails`, which has been mutated. When you `console.log` in `render` you see the new value because `render` is called after state has been updated.

An additional note: You [should not mutate state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) (i.e. using `splice`) instead you should only change state using `setState`. For this problem you can set `this.state.emails` equal to a `slice` of `this.state.emails`. Here's an example:

```
this.setState({ emails: this.state.emails.slice(0, -1) });
```

Comment: Thanks... I knew that I might have been mutating it the original but I wasnt sure what problems it would cause or the right way to actually do it. When I googled how to remove an item from an array using setState everything was saying to use splice.

Comment: Yeah it's good to know because you can get some spooky results when state gets mutated independently of `setState`.